# POST parameters to PHPUnit test

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm new on testing, I'm using PHPUnit to write test. All the site has been designed using the MVC pattern.

I would like to test each method on my controllers, the problem is that such methods receives the parameters though the $_POST variable. How can I overwrite this variable?

Thanks in advance 
Alejandra

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The best approach would be to abstract the Request into a separate class and not access the superglobals at all. This way you decouple the actual server and request environment from the application. You can then mock the Request easily.

Comment: But there is a need to test this request separate class. How would be the best approach to do this?

Comment: @ViktorTodorov with a unit test. And if you want to test it with against multiple SAPIs: with an integration test

Answer (score 21):

First, if you are using Zend_Test, use

```
$this->request->setMethod('POST')->setPost(array(insert array info here));
```

If your not using that, try this:

Warning: Not the best solution, but it will work!

Put this in your setUp fixture

```
 protected function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $_POST = array();
    }
```

Then before you call your test just do something similar to this:

```
$_POST = array(insert array data here)
```

Comment: The first part of this answer was VERY helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Even the second part helped me with TYPO3 and Unit tests

Answer (score 13):

Even if some will say it's not *clean*, you could set data in `$_POST`, before callng your methods : it's not read only ;-)